# Making an array with random repeated values within a range?

Tags: php

I'm making a small function in PHP that, like described in the title, need an array filled with random numbers inside a specified range, the numbers **MUST** repeat within it. As an example, filling an array with 20 random numbers between 1 and 10 should result in something like this:

`Array = [2,5,8,2,8,5,3,9,6,3,4,6,3,1,2,1,2,3,7,1]`

Comment: Just a note: When there are 20 numbers and only 10 values are possible, there must be some numbers repeating.

Comment: please show us your best attempt (code) - where exactly are you stuck and what debugging effort have you done? Please read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code creates an array (`$arr = array();`) and then 20 times (the loop) [pushes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) a random value on the end of the array.

The values are generated by [`random_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) function that generates numbers in the given range (inclusively).

```php
<?php

$arr = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
    array_push($arr, random_int(1, 10));
}
```

The source of randomness is quite good (depending on the system).

If you want such random number array generator as a function, do this:

```php
<?php

function random_ints($count, $min, $max) {
    $arr = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        array_push($arr, random_int($min, $max));
    }
}
```